# How to use a block as a field?

Tags: 7, entities, files, javascript

I'm working with this module which is providing me a block for uploading the file as mentioned in the doc https://drupal.org/project/jquery_file_upload

Is there a way, where I can use this block as a field while adding the content, for instance at `node/add/[my_custom_content]`?

Comment: Maybe you can add a little bit more detail about what exactly you want to achieve? Is it maybe, that you would like to change the weight of your block in a way that it can be displayed in any order within the node edit form?

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal 7 block_reference module will allow you to select a block as a field.  But you need to be careful that you don't also enable the global block for that path, or you'll get TWO of the same block.

https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference

Answer (score 1):

No, fields are totally independent concept than blocks. Of course there is a way to have a region inside field, and you could then drop that block to region, but there would be no connection between block's uploading capabilities and created node.

If you have a fancy file uploading requirements, it would be better to write them down and ask what module can do it for your file or image field.

Comment: I like your suggestion of having region inside field, will it work for my condition, for this module https://drupal.org/project/jquery_file_upload ?

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha But what do you want? If you want to use it as a eplacement for file field, then nope.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module DS(https://drupal.org/project/DS), or else use block api in your content body(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7).

Comment: Why is this voted down? You _can_ add a block field using display suite..

Answer (score 0):

yes - you cannot use blocks as fields ..

the plupload module does exactly what you want,
[combinated with filefield](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload).

Comment: I'm not looking for a different module, I'm looking for a way to display block as a field in D7

Comment: if you really want to make a block as field, you need to write a custom module providing you that block as a field ... - consider changing the module ;)